# Какие средства предпочтительнее использовать для создания "портала"

Tags: cms, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Команде новичков предстоит создать тематический областной портал. По сути он представляет из себя сайт с объявлениями с доп. возможностями: привязка объявления к месту на карте; рейтинг для объявлений сферы услуг. Также в концепции присутствуют коллективные боги и форум, возможно наполнение сайта справочной информацией. 
Какие gem'ы лучше использовать для таких целей, есть ли смысл в CMS для таких проектов, какие преимущества и недостатки в использовании объектных баз данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для авторизации через социальные сети используйте [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth). Для гео-данных - [geocoder](http://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder). Для репутаций пользователей и прочих рейтингов [activerecord-reputation-systeme](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-systeme).

CMS для таких проектов нет смысла использовать.

ps: купите ребятам платную подписку на [скринкасты](http://railscasts.com), там всё это есть (: